# Playing with robots for kids - Which letter will I reach?

Tags: code-golf, simulation

> **TL;DR:** Given an array of chars and a robot in a starting position of the array, write an algorithm than can read a string with movements (`F` for "go forward", `R` for "rotate 90 degrees right" and `L` for "rotate 90 degrees left") and calculate the ending position of the robot. More details in the complete text.

We have at home a very simple programmable device for kids: a small vehicle with buttons to make the vehicle go forward, turn 90 degrees left or turn 90 degrees right. Something similar to this:

[image: Mouse vehicle]

We also have a foam mat with letters like this:

[image: Playing mat]

The purpose of all this is to teach the kids both the alphabet and the rudiments of programming, all at once.

#### The challenge

Suppose we have randomly arranged our foam mat like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| E | R | L | B | I | X | N |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| O | A | Q | Y | C | T | G |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| F | W | H | P | D | Z | S |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    | K | V | U | M | J |   
    +---+---+---+---+---+
            |   |
            +---+
```

Suppose also we have modified the vehicle so that when we program a "go forward" command, the vehicle goes forward exactly size of one square in the mat. So, if the vehicle is in the `U` square and goes north, it stops exactly in the `P` square.

The instructions are all given to the vehicle before it starts to move, and those are:

- `F`: The vehicle goes forward into the next square.
- `R`: The vehicle turns 90 degrees right in its place (no further movement).
- `L`: The vehicle turns 90 degrees left in its place (no further movement).

Once the instructions are given, you can press the "GO" button and send the vehicle to a given position as it will follow every instruction in the given order. So, you can tell the kid to insert the needed instructions for the vehicle to go to a given letter.

You must write the shortest program/function that processes a `string` (input parameter) with a set of instructions and calculates the letter the vehicle stops over (output `string`).

Details:

- The vehicle always starts at the blank square at the bottom, and facing north (towards the `U` square).
- The input string will contain only the letters `F`, `R`, `L` and `G` (for the "go" button). You can use lowercase letters for the mat and the instructions, if you prefer so.
- The algorithm must obey every instruction in the string before the first `G` (every instruction after that is ignored as the vehicle has started moving).
- If the vehicle goes out of the mat at any given moment (even if the input string has not been completely processed), the algorithm must return the string `Out of mat`.
- If not, the algorithm must return the letter the vehicle has stopped over. The starting point counts as a  char (or an empty string).

#### Examples:

```
Input: FFG
Output: P

Input: FRFRFG
Output: Out of mat

Input: RRFFG
Output: Out of mat

Input: FFFRFFLFG
Output: X

Input: FFFRFFLF
Output:      <-- Nothing or a whitespace (the robot has not started moving)

Input: FFFRRFFFG
Output:      <-- Nothing or a whitespace (the robot has returned to the starting point)

Input: RRRRRLFFFLFFRFRFGFFRRGRFF
Output: L    (Everything after the first G is ignored)
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest program for each language win!

Comment: Next up: same thing, but with the mat configuration as string input, with `@` being the starting position and spaces being off the mat, so this config would be `ERLBIXN\nOAQYCTG\nFWHPDZS\n KVUMJ \n   @` (with different spacing, SE messed it up)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>194</s> <s>176</s> <s>169</s> 163 bytes

Saved some bytes thanks to @Luke and @Arnauld.

```
s=>(p=35,d=3,t='ERLBIXN1OAQYCTG1FWHPDZS11KVUMJ11111 11',[...s].every(i=>i=='L'?d--:i>'Q'?d++:i<'G'?+t[p+=[1,8,-1,-8][d%4]]||!t[p]?p=1/0:p:0)?'':t[p]||'Out of mat')
```

Ungolfed:

```
s=>(
  p=35,
  d=3,
  t='ERLBIXN1OAQYCTG1FWHPDZS11KVUMJ11111 11',
  [...s].every(i=>i=='L'?d--:
                  i<'Q'?d++:
                  i<'G'?+t[p+=[1,8,-1,-8][d%4]]||!t[p]?p=1/0:p:
                  0
              )?'':
               t[p]||'Out of mat'
)
```

```js
f=
s=>(p=35,d=3,t='ERLBIXN1OAQYCTG1FWHPDZS11KVUMJ11111 11',[...s].every(i=>i=='L'?d--:i>'Q'?d++:i<'G'?+t[p+=[1,8,-1,-8][d%4]]||!t[p]?p=1/0:p:0)?'':t[p]||'Out of mat')

console.log(f('FFG')); //P
console.log(f('FRFRFG')); //Out of mat
console.log(f('RRFFG')); //Out of mat
console.log(f('FFFRFFLFG')); //X
console.log(f('FFFRFFLF')); //(space)
console.log(f('FFFRRFFFG')); //(space)
console.log(f('RRRRRLFFFLFFRFRFGFFRRGRFF')); //L
console.log(f('FFFFFRRFG')); //Out of mat
```

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by replacing `false` with `!1`

Comment: Thanks, @Luke.  I can actually save a bunch of bytes by removing the "G" test altogether.  If it's not "L", "R", or "F" it can be assumed to be "G" (unless "G" is missing).  Either way, the `every` method handles it.

Comment: Here's a solution for 165 bytes: `(s,p=35,d=3,t='ERLBIXN1OAQYCTG1FWHPDZS11KVUMJ11111 11')=>[...s].every(i=>i=='L'?d--:i=='R'?d++:i=='F'?+t[p+=[1,8,-1,-8][d%4]]||!t[p]?p=1/0:1:0)?'':t[p]||'Out of mat'`

Comment: Not sure how that gets me to 165 bytes(?)  But I certainly don't need a separate variable for the `[1,8,-1,-8]` array, thanks!

Comment: Oops, must have miscounted, it's 171. I also removed a space you don't need, which still is in the current answer (it's the last space).

Comment: Of course, thanks!  Now down to 169 bytes.

Comment: @Arnauld, good points both!  The parentheses were left over from a previous more-complicated answer.

Comment: You can also do `i<'G'` instead of `i=='F'`.

Comment: Instead of doing `t[p...]==1`, you could do `+t[p...]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>226</s> <s>231</s> 241 bytes

Second edit; should work now. Again, plenty of optimization to be done.

```python
n=input();s="0ERLBIXN00OAQYCTG00FWHPDZS000KVUMJ000000 00000";d=1;c=40;i=0;w=[-1,-9,1,9]
while n[i]!="G"and c>=0:
 if n[i]=="F":c+=w[d]
 else:d=[d+[-1,3][d<0],-~d%4][n[i]=="R"]
 i+=1
print(["Out of mat",s[c]][c in range(len(s))and s[c]!="0"])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU5La8MwGLvnV3iGQUIc@EJ7abxvsJezR7d22XvGh2CnqyFzQ@MSetlfz5pQHXSQhKRm79cbN@l7h9Y1Ox9GvEUKN8X88u7zCWBx8fx19ZoDiI/b5fX3CwA8vL893sMIMjLlBlOucQrcIvAOZZKyZMZSNlNBt7Z1RZy06gRpTktniD5HyAJiV6OMSAXNdIydNCogVd1WmUFp4qFloqQ5A8WSP3M6VfKYL@ghaGNMg2ZrnQ8lXew82azIb@kpa6VWSmpiHdmW7qcK68qFbRQN04N3@AFURX0vhCiEmIv8Hw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 235 bytes

```python
x=0;y=1;a=4;b=3
p='ERLBIXN','OAQYCTG','FWHPDZS','aKVUMJ','aaa '
r=''
for i in input():
 if'G'==i:r=p[a][b];break
 elif'G'>i:
  b+=x;a-=y;
  if(-1<a<5)-1or(''<p[a][b:]<'a')-1:r='Out of mat';break
 else:x,y=[[y,-x],[-y,x]][i<'R']
print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBJb4MwEIXv/hVWLkNUkEqXCzCVupkutGlpuiIfTGoUqykgh6jw6@kQIlW1ffj83psZ2XXXLKvyoF9Unxonk0nf4n7YoR8qPApzPGQ1wmWanF2/3YMLs9PH9/N5TCRerx4uPp6I1O3L893NAEpxYBYBWFFZbrgp6dSbxpkGjJsCYkA0gcU6UzLLZZhbrb4Y16utd2IoxfM9bEPlYRfSxRSO50cqOp56fmUdgGgsDWQECkikZjDbNLwq@Ldq4K/jWget22GWda7XSjfzOreVMjMRpCBZbU3ZcNvTe9nP0qw0n9uNHsbrVi/48Bc9CBEDA5HSHiBNd4IgQST/eIfEuyitRAzOWD54MbljbpuM4Rc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com/language)/Mathematica, 300 Bytes

```
p=Re[(1-7I)#[[1]]]&;d=Drop;t=Throw;s=Switch;s[#,0,"Out of mat",_,StringPart["000 0000KVUMJ0FWHPDZSOAQYCTGERLBIXN",p@#]]&@Catch@Fold[If[MemberQ[d[d[Range[4,35],{2,5}],{7}],p@#],#,t@0]&@(s[#2,"F",#+{#[[2]],0},"R",#{1,-I},"L",#{1,I},_,t[#]]&)[#1,#2]&,{4,I},If[StringFreeQ["G"]@#,{"G"},Characters@#]&@#]&
```

Ungolfed:

```
p = Re[(1 - 7 I) #[[1]]] &;
d = Drop;
t = Throw;
s = Switch;
s[#,
    0, "Out of mat",
    _, StringPart["000 0000KVUMJ0FWHPDZSOAQYCTGERLBIXN", p@#]] &@
  Catch@
  Fold[
    If[MemberQ[d[d[Range[4, 35], {2, 5}], {7}], p@#], #, 
        t@0] &@(s[#2, "F", # + {#[[2]], 0}, "R", # {1, -I}, 
          "L", # {1, I}, _, t[#]] &)[#1, #2] &,
    {4, I},
    If[StringFreeQ["G"]@#, {"G"}, Characters@#] &@#] &
```