# Does a letter fit inside the other?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, alphabet

Do you remember [my mat properly grouped by colors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/148927/70347)?

[image: My mat properly grouped by colors]

Yesterday I was looking at it and realized that some letters fit inside others. Example: a letter `P` fits in the place where the letter `R` goes. So here's a simple challenge: given two letters, return a truthy value if any one of the letters fits inside the other (directly or rotated, but not flipped), or a falsey value if they don't. That is, if the input is `[P,R]` or `[R,P]`, you must return truthy because in both cases one letter fits inside the other. If you get `[L,U]` you must return falsey as neither fit inside the other.

**Rules**

- The input must be two alphanumeric characters in the range [0-9A-Z], as there are also numbers in the mat, in any form you need (two separate chars as two inputs, a list with two chars, a string with the 2 chars, whatever).
- The output must be consistent (the truthy and falsey values must be always the same).
- Following is the table of fittings (note that a letter always fits in its proper place, just in case you get something like `[Y,Y]` as input):

  ```
  char fits inside chars
  --------------------------------------------------------
     C             G,O
     F             B,E,P,R
     G             O
     I             0,1,7,B,D,E,F,H,K,L,M,N,O,P,R,T,V,W,X,Z
     L             E
     M             W
     P             R
     S             O
     V             A
     W             M
     0             O
     1             B,E,L
     3             O
     6             9,O
     8             O
     9             6,O
  ```

I solemnly swear that I have tested every fitting in my kid's mat. *(Dries his sweat from his forehead.)*

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code for each language win!

**Some test cases**

```
input  output
-------------
[C,G]  truthy (C fits inside G)
[G,C]  truthy (C fits inside G)
[F,R]  truthy (F fits inside R)
[M,W]  truthy (both fit inside the other)
[O,S]  truthy (S fits inside O)
[T,T]  truthy (T fits in its place)
[E,V]  falsey (no fit found)
[P,L]  falsey
```

---

[Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14425/70347). Please, forgive me if you spot more fittings that I missed. Many thanks to [Οurous](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/18730/%CE%9Furous) for helping me with the fittings list.

Comment: [tag:kolmogorov-complexity].

Comment: `1` doesn't fit in `F`?

Comment: @user202729 no, because you need to flip the `1` to fit it in the `F` but that's not allowed in my mat. :-)

Comment: Ah, it's rotation.

Comment: [Illustration ASCII-art graph](https://tio.run/##dY3JCsJAEETv@Yr3AR2iCC4ggrviigYVkeTkRXIWJOO3a3rI4DbWoZuiHlWXc5bdHipUOUthJkyEhjAQYuEgHIMy3UHYoevsgnZh986ONFzr2VCqKWyFGtyDqQY5hhNfatmaukJl0xVS8wn17fS4gPSvHNnTN@RX6Vtdoi/xQJF5QXbPeBgHVHV4/j@vEHoUPQE) (of course fit-in is transitive)

Comment: @Rod yes, and the result would be truthy as a letter always fits in its proper place. I have edited the question.

Comment: i think we'd all really appreciate test cases :p

Comment: @BrianH. sorry for that, I added some test cases. Feel free to ask for more.

Comment: Do C and O not fit inside Q in your font?

Comment: @Zgarb probably. I completely forgot about the `Q`, but I cannot change the challenge now.

Comment: @Charlie Only two answers so far, wouldn't be too much disruption?

Comment: @Οurous it was in [this other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/151276/find-the-longest-word-in-an-array#comment369760_151276) when it already had two answers... Besides, the challenge already has many cases to test, more cases won't add anything to it (I think the most creative part is that the two inputs are interchangeable as you have to check both fittings).

Comment: Why does `I` fit inside `0`?

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>135</s> <s>130</s> 129 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)

```python
lambda s:cmp(*s)%2*s[::cmp(*s)|1]in'OIH TIE XI7 RF O8 OGC LI0 O3 O96 VA O6 KI PI WI L1 WMI O0 RIB NI1 FE SOC VID ZIFB1 PF LE1 RP'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NccxS8NAGIDh3V/xLnJt6dCrUDXg0MZc/DD1C2lIpOpQlWDApqG5RfC/R25weeDpf/zXqVuOzd3r@H04vn8eGKKPYz@ZDdPL5Wx4if73a9/azqg8UErCs1xTOPQGTWMyWaBX6O2Kao2ueBRyoRYyS70VdEEhG57E4hJ2GlPJPXtxG0vuyBJLkZuxOZ3xtB0mTs0ck8ZBVwS3dVB3wbIMJlUwz0x0Af257Tx@TjPx0/EP)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 143 bytes

```python
lambda*i:any({*i}&{a,c}=={*i}for a,b in zip('CFGILMPSVW013689','GO BEPR O 017BDEFHKLMNOPRTVWXZ E W R O A M O BEL O 9O O 6O'.split())for c in b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc1NC4JAEIDhe79iTu1aSyhBH4KHNLVI28VEI7qshrRgKualot9uzq3Lw8AM8zav7l5X876wrn0pH9lNTpQpqxf9TNR3/JEs/1oWzkXdgmQZqAreqqHE8fx9EIpTkurGfLFaE0Z8DrYrIuCgG0t763q7QxAeuYjiJD1fwIUUcLmBEPAyGFzzgQUns2dTqo5qGmZyjGRa/5ckjk8YEN9BvQgNU5Sf0DhG3QQVATFHAE2rqo7KacagoJIN/7T@Bw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>93</s> 92 bytes

```
O`.
(.)\1|1[BEL]|69|AV|CG|BF|EF|EL|FP|FR|[017BDEFH]I|I[KLMNOPRTVWXZ]|MW|PR|OS|[03689CG]O

^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxDsIgFAXQ/X2HJnVpJCbVjoKAjVQIbaARMXVwcHEwjvffsckZz/f1e3@eZV3pudi5pqre3BlY4tJkNC2OAUKDK8iFgXJQHmnL9vwk1Tl36NLF9Ffr/BjidMvoI5yHHZa0aw6t0NkSPValCE1akPLUR7IDjSPJQM78AQ) Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @ovs.

Comment: Does [this](https://tio.run/##DcqxDsIgFAXQ/X2HJnVpJCbVjoKAjVQIbaARMXVwcHEwjvffsckZz/f1e3@eZV3pudi5pqre3BlY4tJkNC2OAUKDK8iFgXJQHmnL9vwk1Tl36NLF9Ffr/BjidMvoI5yHHZa0aw6t0NkSPValCE1akPLUR7IDjSPJQM78AQ) work for 92 bytes?

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript <s>155 153 151</s> 149 bytes

I think this works on all cases, 1/0 for true/false.

```
(c,f,q=1)=>"CGO,FBEPR,GO,I017BDEFHKLMNOPRTVWXZ,LE,MW,PR,SO,VA,WM,0O,1BEL,3O,69O,8O,96O".split`,`.some((v=>v[0]==c&v.includes(f)))|c==f|(q?F(f,c,0):0)
```

Explanation:

```
F=(
c, // input 1
f, // input 2
q=1 // variable used to execute F twice
)=>(
"CGO,FBEPR,GO,I017BDEFHKLMNOPRTVWXZ,LE,MW,PR,SO,VA,WM,0O,1BEL,3O,69O,8O,96O".split`,` 
                              // array of strings where [0] is input 1 and [>0] are the fittings
.some(                        // any element of the array meets:
(v=>v[0]==c&v.includes(f)))|  // input 1 equals [0] and input 2  exists in the lookup string OR
c==f|                         // input 1 equals input 2 OR
(q?F(f,c,0):0)                // input 2 fits inside input 1
```

```js
let F=(c,f,q=1)=>"CGO,FBEPR,GO,I017BDEFHKLMNOPRTVWXZ,LE,MW,PR,SO,VA,WM,0O,1BEL,3O,69O,8O,96O".split`,`.some((v=>v[0]==c&v.includes(f)))|c==f|(q?F(f,c,0):0);
let tests = [
  ["C","G"],  //truthy (C fits inside G)
  ["G","C"],  //truthy (C fits inside G)
  ["F","R"],  //truthy (F fits inside R)
  ["M","W"],  //truthy (both fit inside the other)
  ["O","S"],  //truthy (S fits inside O)
  ["T","T"],  //truthy (T fits in its place)
  ["E","V"],  //falsey (no fit found)
  ["P","L"]   //falsey
];
tests.forEach((v)=>{console.log("F('"+v[0]+"','"+v[1]+"') = " + F(v[0],v[1]))});
```

### Changelog:

- saved 2 bytes thanks to kamoroso94
- saved 2 bytes thanks to Chris M
- saved 2 bytes by changing lookup method to .some()

Comment: Does this return true if `c` fits `f` or `f` fits `c`? It seems that you only check one case.

Comment: Code fixed to return true if `f` fits `c`

Comment: I'm not too good explaining, if anybody wants to make it clearer feel free to suggest an edit

Comment: You can use `includes(f)` instead of `indexOf(f)>=0` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: awesome, didn't even know that was a thing :D

Comment: You can save another two by using split`,` instead of split(",")

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>276</s> 226 bytes

Vaguely golfed-ish. Will polish tomorrow.

```
import StdEnv
i a b=isMember b a
t=True
f'C'b=i['GO']b
f'F'b=i['BEPR']b
f'O'b=i['GS03689']b
f'I'b=i['017BDEFHKLMNOPRTVWXZ']b
f'L''E'=t
f'P''R'=t
f'V''A'=t
f'M''W'=t
f'1'b=i['BEL']b
f'6''9'=t
f _ _=False
?a b=a==b||f a b||f b a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY9Ba8JAEIXv@RVzm5OgFLQeFqmaWGnShERUWkRmk01ZyMaSrIWCv73bTcee9nvv7TDzykZR68ylujYKDOnWafN56SwUtgrbr0ADgRS6T5SRqgMJFFix664qqHGFPnnHTYon6WXEchlmORvpPS/GD9PHOXtb9saT2XIdRs8vcfKaZvlufzi@8YcYMURhPWWIOdMe8YkpQTwwTf63xTw3RZz/JXCGs4io6VWwGG4nIeTtVg89hsc3cIUl31DAAvwM@DvdT1k39NG7UfXdktGlp23s1nfxCw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>149</s> 145 bytes

```hs
[]!_=0>1
(a:b:c)!t=(a,b)==t||(b,a)==t||c!t
f x y=x==y||"0I0O1B1E1I1L3O696O7I8O9OAVBFBICGCODIEFEIELFIFPFRGOHIIKILIMINIOIPIRITIVIWIXIZMWOSPR"!(x,y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdFRa8IwEADg9/6Kaxk0wQ4sg20KEbRru8N2KbXomIhEqShTJ7ayFvrfu6TDuYcmD0nuC8ldshXZZ7rf1/V8oS9Zd2BrRPRX/TXVc0aEtaKM5VVFVpb4na31XNtAASUrGCuryuhil9sj27XRDh74Y@@RP@Ez7/HhdOSN0PEd/oKu56IbeOhFXuzzV8QxBhjiG3KMMMYEpzjDd/wIZ3wSxYZOCqukdZ5muSOyNAMGcw1kI8R0TAtM36QWJOdLCtS6gq/AaQFPQdwCoYJZC3AFkxZIFCQt4CqYKvDEPktvECkIbtDEF5qmapNeWFBKE8eMyiJPl3ySn4Mj3DXbsu3Xt3zpTgcM2eXQBEo5a9iA@8G/OGl@hV51t4EmAIyp4yHfpke5m/AxNSCVqciFN8RANzTtIHZHef1BnMIlNJn9PX39Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 139 bytes

```julia
(a,b)->(a==b)|any(map(x->all(in.((a,b),x))|all(in.((b,a),x)),zip("OCFILMPV16",split("CGS0368 G BEPR 017BDEFHKLMNOPRTVWXZ E W R A BEL 9"))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrBSsNAEAbge59iWAo7C9vQIkQ9pGBjEsXEhDQkpbcJGlhZ11ArVPHd45DFucw3//xvX9ZQOA3RhKR7tdoiRVGvfsl94zuNeFltyVo0LsC5oC@Kn/9Jr2lO9I8ZUZRx@pgXVbsJhf4crTmjiLP9@iq8gQx2SVXDenO9u0/Sh6e8eC6rumm7wxES6KCGO27kcCsUzzR8nIDAOECUsdQyk0oD8tJ8zkyZtWfB7DxL5t6zYTaeCbP1rJi5VGoBPOPJuLN1KJYESxyQgiBQSqjFq3uZ/gA)

Saved some bytes by grouping the chars that fit into 'O'. But testing the reversed input uses too much code...

Explanation:

- `zip(☐)` zips corresponding single letters from `"OCFILMPV16"` & a string of matching letters.
- `.in(☐)` is applied elementwise, e.g. `(in(a,'O'),in(b,"OCFILMPV16"))`
- `all(.in(☐))` Both must be found...
- `|` for either `a,b` or `b,a`...
- `any(map(☐))` for at least one element of the zipped list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>147</s> 139 bytes

```
fun p(s:String)=setOf(s,s.reversed()).any{it.matches(Regex("(.)\\1|F[BEPR]|I[017BDEFHKLMNOPRTVWXZ]|1[BEL]|69|CG|LE|MW|PR|VA|O[CG69038S]"))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rdfvi6JAGAfw9/0Vc9KLEZZIuquMayHLStJmzsLCNljbxk2utdBpacn@9s5YloU99r4s3uA7PzqPzzO//L2T2yi@XMJDTPY0bU1kEsWPajsVkoU0vUkriXgWSSrWVFUrQfxyimTlKZAPG5FSVzyKI1VoRb2707L@wjC5u8ysRVVrGD2zPxzZzphxd@rN5v4y0/L79jKr61l3kNlm5swy7mZeJ2OL7qCuV2vNyVJR1XNpn0TPgRQkisPoSK6RvUZVuQ8jSdLN7rBdk5W4p6sWMXa7rQhilZxKJG/5o7HcxlQxj3vxIMWaXB8Jdwkpy02Ukvwqr0i7fUvKpyikq3Z7T683VFVhI4WIbSqIMmLf8qacFbV0Ll27fwqimAatTpIELz9fY7l96/HalO5AIR@CIzI5iHcx6CLRd5FwZkiwCRLTKRKm97cIgzwx74Tbn5GvpKTLYEoMKEwoePHED2CkVhUKDYoGFDAfVg8KmDGrD8UQihEUNhQOFGMocOXg@LDg@LDgpLI8KODktuZQ@EjYZvFFhsN8TGDWvQ4SM1j9KuxFg/NFg/nQ4DitwTjqOhTwHU0o9DoUn73jK/sUg8KAC4gJBYfChYLBLahqwfJD0YDCgKIHhQlFH4ohFCMobCgcKMZQMCg4FC4UUyg8KGZQzKHwcfXt4suly4ufHjvefzijwqOSAY9KJhQ2FKxWfEFlWDSLbw5Mh8s2h8Wtwc/1fdiNo8N/g18/8O9DE5Iah8T/Dsm88S9yvlz@AA)

The example on *Try It Online* includes test cases for every positive combination and a few negative ones.

I haven't optimized the reg.ex. too much, so it might be longer than necessary

**EDIT:** saved a few bytes on reg.ex.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 211 bytes

A first attempt. Very straight-forward.

```c
i;char*c="CFGILMPSVW013689",*x[]={"GO","BEPR","O","017BDEFHKLMNOPRTVWXZ","E","W","R","O","A","M","O","BEL","O","9O","O","6O"};h(a,b){return(i=strchr(c,a)-c)>=0&&strchr(x[i],b);}f(a,b){return a==b|h(a,b)|h(b,a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1Ra4MwFIWf66@QQGssKbQMunWSwtqpG9MpVnSs7UPM2ipsMlKFjs7f7m5WA3tYyM093@WcGz46cN62hcVzJoacoqXjPnp@uErS8eRqejNDZHhab@kZuQEiaGGHETQpx5Prxb3tPDx5/nMQRnGSvrzC2IZKoZTtDsrv9ML2OjULOjENUGPlmJHMPItdVYsSF/RYCZ4LzAkzR9yc0/Fg0I1O62ILVqvZ/43ojNLs@7IFWgY5q2mLstIPWL6M6LJlpnbWep8C9B6jPtfh0rnef9uUiEhTRnS5F4ympTWaJkMfrCjxJVhXR4xiUVf51@2mHF0OAmvvgI2lQQzX6MAFWCpwACIFPkCqIABYKYgB4l9QX21Kh70fd/98ZoM3UcEQwJPQtD8)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 204 bytes

*-147 bytes because I cam back to remove 2 bytes only to find that my code had a few bugs and unused variables! My code is now much shorter.*

```php
<?php $a=fgets(STDIN);for($w=0;$w<2;$w++){if(strpos(explode(',','GO,BEPR,O,017BDEFHKLMNOPRTVWXZ,E,W,R,O,A,M,O,BEL,O,9O,O,6O')[strpos(CFGILMPSVW013689,$a[0])],$a[1])!==false){echo"t";break;}$a=strrev($a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5tC4IwHMS/SsWgjf4vtMCKJdGDWqRNLDQSX6yaGQUOlQqiz24T4uB3L@44TmayridTmckW4mZ6FVWJd/vlektomhcYvUyNotekr9Drkc8txWVVyLzE4i0f@UXgLig5DOaWHwADTR/Ol5a92rjelvnBPowOR7AggiacgQdN01UcMwWDdUn8H1zYztr1/F0YafrAGI0B8VhLSNK4npC2aab8UQryEecs71QdeioEv9Ovuq0WCvHEiBP6revA/gE)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 140 bytes

```
->c,t{x='CFGILMPSVW013689'.chars.zip('GO BEPR O 017BDEFHKLMNOPRTVWXZ E W R O A M O BEL O 9O O 6O'.split).to_h;p x.key?(c)&&x[c].include?(t)}
```

Pretty much the same as the python 3 answer, but with a different execution.